# Install gem linecache19 : syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-debug

I have tried to install a couple of ways but failed each time. Can you help? The outcome is always the same:

```
...
creating Makefile

make
generating trace_nums-i386-mingw32.def
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `Init_trace_nums.sub(/'
/usr/bin/sh: -c: line 1: `C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby -e \puts EXPORTS,  + Init_trace_nums.sub(/\..*\z/,)\  > trace_nums-i386-mingw32.def'
make: *** [trace_nums-i386-mingw32.def] Error 258
```

I've seen several related posts, but none with this message. I'm using **pik**, in case that makes a difference.

I don't know how to interpret this error message. If I should be opening one of the gem source files and correcting its syntax, what file has this issue? (I've opened several in search.)

**Specs:** Windows 7, Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.3

### What I've tried:

I have tried on the command line:

```
gem install linecache19
```

I have tried adding it to my Gemfile, then calling `bundle install`

```
gem 'linecache19'
```

I have tried downloading it from rubyforge and calling:

```
gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem
```

Comment: I remember having problems with that gem the last time I've tried to install it (it works fine now though). Can you try downloading (http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=8883&release_id=38668) and installing it with `gem install ruby-debug19-*.gem`?

Comment: @Sammy, no dice. Looks like my problem stems from an inability to install native components of the gem linecache19. (Per your advice, I downloaded linecache19-0.5.13.gem from rubyforge.org and tried to install it w/ your command, but it raised the same error.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded at this after almost a month. The solution was to use Ruby DevKit. Instructions for its installation (don't just unpack it) are [here](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit).